# Laravel SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'testimonial_by' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `testimonials`

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

[SOLVED]I'm facing problems trying to fix the following error.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'testimonial_by' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `testimonials` (`testimonial_by`, `testimonial_text`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (John Doe, Lorem Ipsum is really lit!, 2019-10-02 20:37:53, 2019-10-02 20:37:53))

I have added my code related to 'testimonials' below.

**app/Testimonial.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Testimonial extends Model
{
    public $guarded = [];

    public function allTestimonials()
    {
        return self::all();
    }
}
```

**TestimonialController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Testimonial;

class TestimonialController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $testimonials = Testimonial::all();
        return view('dashboard.testimonials.index')->withTestimonials($testimonials);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('dashboard.testimonials.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate(['testimonial_text'=>'required']);
        $testimonial = Testimonial::create($request->all());
        if($testimonial)
        {
            $this->success('Testimonial added successfully');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->error();
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    public function edit(Testimonial $testimonial)
    {
        return view('dashboard.testimonials.edit')->withTestimonial($testimonial);
    }

    public function update(Testimonial $testimonial,Request $request)
    {
        if($testimonial->update($request->all()))
        {
            $this->success('Testimonial Updated Successfully');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->error();
        }
        return redirect()->route('dashboard.testimonials.index');
    }

    public function destroy(Testimonial $testimonial)
    {
        if($testimonial->delete())
        {
            $this->success('Testimonial Deleted Successfully');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->error();
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

**migration**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTestimonialsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('testimonials', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('testimonials');
    }
}
```

I can't seem to find where I'm going wrong. Thank you for your time and support.

Comment: I don't see any code using `testimonial_by`. Where is that error happening?

Comment: Looking at your migration you also don't seem to have a column `testimonial_text`. `$testimonial = Testimonial::create($request->all());` Do you have a form with inputs named `testimonial_by` and `testimonial_text`? You need to add those to your migration

Comment: The `Testimonial::create($request->all());` line is very scary

Comment: @CaddyDZ: why is that? can you elaborate?

Comment: A use can alter the HTMlL of the frontend and post more data that OP is going to pass to eloquent `create` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help. I found out where I was going wrong.

I added the following likes to my migrations

```
        $table->string('testimonial_by');
        $table->string('testimonial_text');
```

Then i tried running `php artisan migrate` but I still got the same error.

So, I went and created the columns on my own and simple ran the project and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add those columns to your migration:

```php
Schema::create('testimonials', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('testimonial_by'); // or $table->integer('testimonial_by'); if a user ID 
    $table->string('testimonial_text');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: add a commented reference to the foreign key

Comment: I see i also don't have the columns in my table. Do I have to make the columns using  `php artisan make:migration ........`  or just go to phpmyadmin and make the  columns?

Comment: If you have already ran the migration once, you will need to undo it before you run it again. I see you already added it manually, but in the future: run `php artisan migrate:rollback` and then `php artisan migrate` again. If you have already created and ran other migrations, you will have to create a new migration to add columns. here is the link in the docs to add a column https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations#creating-columns

Comment: Notice: `migrate:rollback` will remove your table and all data. Adding a second migration is necessary if you need to preserve data in other columns.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have fields with names (testimonial_by and testimonial_text) in the form. But they are absent in migration. Can you open your DB and look at columns?
If they are absent - add to migration

```
$table->string('testimonial_by'); //or integet
$table->string('testimonial_text');
```

PS. you may need in the future in model `protected $fillable = [array with column names for filling];`

Comment: Hi, I added them to the migrations. I just found out that these columns don't exist on my table. Should I make them using migrations? or just make them phpmyadmin?

Comment: remove the particular migration entry from `migrations` table and run `php artisan:migrate` again to reflect the new changes..

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to your migration..

```
Schema::create('testimonials', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->string('testimonial_by',200); 
$table->text('testimonial_text');
$table->timestamps();
});
```

In your model add these fields as fillable

```
class Testimonial extends Model
{
public $guarded = [];
public $timestamps = true;
protected $fillable = ['testimonial_text','testimonial_by'];
public function allTestimonials()
{
    return self::all();
}
}
```

Create table entry using required fields only..

```
 $testimonial = Testimonial::create(
    'testimonial_by' => $request->input('testimonial_by'), //put current user name 
    'testimonial_text' => $request->input('testimonial_text')
  );
```

Remove the migration file entry from `migrations` table and run the `php artisan:migrate` command.It will create `testimonials` table with updated columns.